# How to create hashes of hash in Tcl

Tags: arrays, hash, tcl, associative-array

Hope all are doing well.

I am a newbie to the TCL programming language and started working on a project.

I want to create a hash here according to the following table-

[image]

I want to create a hash with the name **MEM_GROUP** and want to access a value **DDR1**, **DDR2**, etc.
Suppose I want to print **DDR3** that comes under the **ownership** of **Person3** then how do I access that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Use tcl [`dict`s](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.html) instead of arrays, to start - they're both hash tables under the hood, but the dict interface explicitly supports easy to use nested tables with chains of keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

set mem_group [dict create]
dict set mem_group Person1 ownership DDR1
dict set mem_group Person2 ownership DDR2
dict set mem_group Person3 ownership DDR3
dict set mem_group Person4 ownership DDR4

puts [dict get $mem_group Person3 ownership]
```